# What is best way to implement dynamic aggregation using Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

By dynamic aggregation I means, the aggregation buckets are different per search query.
Take ebay as example, if search for "iphone"
https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2380057.m570.l1313.TR12.TRC2.A0.H0.Xiphone.TRS0&_nkw=iphone&_sacat=0

The aggregations in left panel are:

- Features
- Network
- Model
- Color
- etc ...

But if search for Book, https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2380057.m570.l1313.TR12.TRC2.A0.H0.Xbook.TRS0&_nkw=book&_sacat=0

The aggregations are:

- Guaranteed Delivery
- Condition
- Price
- Buying Format
- etc...

One possible way to to define same aggregation fields for all documents, and when querying, pass all aggregation fields to query DSL.

But it is so heavy and not flexible.

Is there any simple solutions?

Comment: will you keep Book and Phone in separated ES index?

Comment: no, they will be in same index. In eBay example, I guess they are also in same index, as before the querying, search engine does not know from what index to retrieve "books" or "iphone".